# Retrieving current Active Directory username from PHP

Tags: php, active-directory

For a website on the **Intra**net with all the IE security settings setup. I want to retrieve the current AD username that the user is logged in with. I don't need to authenticate because I am assuming that the person on the computer has already gone through the process.

Is this even possible? I've seen a lot of NTLM related stuff that shows how to authenticate but I can't seem to pull the current authenticated username easily without a prompt box, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

The server setup is a Windows server with Apache. If it is easily done with a Linux machine I can move it there too.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in your question, IE has to be configured to allow Windows Integrated Authentication. Doing so basically gives IE permission to provide your credentials/token to **sites that request it** (usually limited to sites in the Intranet zone). Note that your web site will have to request those credentials (in IIS it is as simple as checking a checkbox). In Apache you'll have to find an Apache module that add NTLM authentication support to your web server. A quick Google search revealed a few different modules, none seemed particularly up to date. If you get an Apache NTLM module working, I suspect you'll be able to access the username via`$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']`.

Comment: I've found those modules for Apache too. However, they want to authenticate against AD a second time. This is not what I want it to do. I just want it to challenge IE (the modules can do) for the tokens and then let me pull the username out of that.